# Timeouting a while loop in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, loops, timeout

This works fine (infinite loop):

```
$ while TRUE; do printf ".";done
```

.............................................................................

I am trying to **timeout** this `while loop` with the `timeout` command.
All these don't work:

```
$ timeout 5 while TRUE; do printf ".";done
$ timeout 5 "while TRUE; do printf ".";done"
$ timeout 5 "while TRUE; do printf \".\";done"
$ timeout 5 $(while TRUE; do printf ".";done)
$ timeout 5 $('while TRUE; do printf ".";done')
```

What is the correct way (if it exists)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think that the solution to your problem is to execute another shell instance and pass proper commands to it.
According to bash manual:

```
-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.
```

Thus my solution would be something like that:

```
timeout 5 bash -c -- 'while true; do printf ".";done'
```

`--` assures that the following arguments will be treated as non-option. And `''` helps with passing `"` without unnecessary escaping

Comment: The answer is correct. But according to forum rules, it would be appropriate some details about those two additional parameters.

Comment: I have added some details to my answer

Answer (score 6):

The alternative at least with bash is something like that:

```bash
start=$EPOCHSECONDS
while <condition>
do
  sleep .2  # (or whatever loop body you have

  if (( EPOCHSECONDS-start > 5 )); then break; fi
done
```

It's not as concise as `timeout` but it's a all built-ins, which has its own advantages.

Answer (score 1):

For a POSIX shell version:

```bash
start_ts=$(date +%s)
while <condition>; do
    now_ts=$(date +%s)
    if [ $(( now_ts - start_ts )) -gt 5 ]; then
        echo "Timeout."
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```