# How to wait for the value of a variable to be set true until a certain time interval

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

**Scenario:**
I have a shell script running on embedded linux. The script starts an application which needs the state of a variable to be on.

**Code:**
So I do it like this

```
#!/bin/sh

start_my_app=false

wait_for_something=true
while $wait_for_something; do

    wait_for_something=$(cat /some/path/file)

    if [ "$wait_for_something" = "false" ]
    then
        echo Waiting...
    elif [ "$wait_for_something" = "true" ]
    then
        echo The wait has ended
        wait_for_something=false
        start_my_app=true
    else

    fi

done

if [ "$start_my_app" = "true" ]
then
    /usr/bin/MyApp
fi

#End of the script
```

`/some/path/file` has a value `false` and turns to `true` in a few seconds by another script in different component. And then as the logic goes `wait_for_something` in my script becomes `true` and `/usr/bin/MyApp` is started.

**The problem and hence the question:**
But I want to do it in a better way.
I dont want to wait infinitely in a while loop expecting the content value in `/some/path/file` to be set `true` after some time.

I want to wait for the content value in `/some/path/file` to be set `true` for only 5 seconds. If `/some/path/file` does not contain `true` in 5 seconds, I want to get out setting `start_my_app` to false.

How can I achieve this functionality in a shell script on linux?

**PS:**
My whole script is run in the background by another script

Comment: You sleep for 2 seconds between each check. Why don't you just stop iterating after 3 times, for a total of ~6 seconds?

Comment: I removed the sleep but I think I can wait on seconds elapsed to count till 6 I guess

Comment: You should probably have at least a small sleep. No point using 100% CPU for five seconds. The alternative is using a named pipe instead of a regular file, which you can just wait on with a timeout.

Comment: ah. ok. Thats a good point I should remove the sleep then. Ok. Another thing I found [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152858/how-do-i-measure-duration-in-seconds-in-a-shell-script), that there is a way to check how much time I waited.

Comment: @thatotherguy I anyways got the answer. I can close the question or happy to accept an answer you post based on the counters technique with sleep 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time condition loop in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11176284/608639) and [Timeouting a while loop in Linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555727/608639). Also see [How to kill a child process after a given timeout in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5161193/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SECONDS` variable as a timer.

```
SECONDS=0
while (( SECONDS < 5 )) && IFS= read -r value < /some/path/file; do
  if [[ $value = true ]]; then
    exec /usr/bin/MyApp
  fi
done
```

If you never read `true` from the file, your script will exit after 5 seconds. Otherwise, the script replaces the current shell with `MyApp`, effectively exiting the `while` loop.

Comment: Good news is that `SECONDS` can be used in a POSIX shell as well, not only in `bash`.

Comment: @ob-ivan `SECONDS` is not defined by POSIX. It's an ordinary variable in `dash`, for example.

Comment: My bad, I didn't test it properly. My loop was exiting before reaching the timeout, so I simply assumed it worked. Incrementing an ordinary variable is a way to go then.